# How can I index a UITableView with the user's iPod Library artists?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uikit, ios5

I want to fetch and index all the iPod Library artists in my app, just like the Music app does. The problem I'm having is that I don't know what's the best way to tackle this problem. Any help?

Comment: Are you still having this problem? As I believe I have a solution for you.

Comment: I will love you if you do. I did a solution but it was slow as hell (by checking for article words, by separating characters...). It's also really slow, so yeah, I will love to hear your solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's name your `UITableViewController` class `LibraryArtistsBrowserTableViewController`

**1. Preparation**

The interface file **LibraryArtistsBrowserTableViewController.h** will contain the following variables:

```
@interface LibraryArtistsBrowserTableViewController : UITableViewController 

@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMediaQuery *artistsQuery;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *artistsArray,*sectionedArtistsArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation;

- (NSArray *)partitionObjects:(NSArray *)array collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector;

@end
```

**2. Indexing**

In your implementation file **LibraryArtistsBrowserTableViewController.m**, put the following code in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Make a query for artists
    self.artistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery artistsQuery];
    //Group by Album Artist
    [self.artistsQuery setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingAlbumArtist];
    //Grab the "MPMediaItemCollection"s and store it in "artistsArray"
    self.artistsArray = [self.artistsQuery collections];

    //We then populate an array "artists" with the individual "MPMediaItem"s that self.artistsArray` contains
    NSMutableArray *artists = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (MPMediaItemCollection *artist in artistsArray) {
        //Grab the individual MPMediaItem representing the collection
        MPMediaItem *representativeItem = [artist representativeItem];
        //Store it in the "artists" array
        [artists addObject:representativeItem];
    }
    //We then index the "artists" array and store individual sections (which will be the alphabet letter and a numbers section), all containing the corresponding MPMediaItems
    self.sectionedArtistsArray = [self partitionObjects:artists collationStringSelector:@selector(albumArtist)];    
}
```

The function we use to section the items is defined below, place this somewhere your implementation file:

```
- (NSArray *)partitionObjects:(NSArray *)array collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    self.collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
    NSInteger sectionCount = [[collation sectionTitles] count];
    NSMutableArray *unsortedSections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++)
        [unsortedSections addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];

    for (id object in array)
    {
        NSInteger index = [self.collation sectionForObject:object collationStringSelector:selector];
        [[unsortedSections objectAtIndex:index] addObject:object];
    }
    NSMutableArray *sections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];
    for (NSMutableArray *section in unsortedSections)
        [sections addObject:[self.collation sortedArrayFromArray:section collationStringSelector:selector]];

    return sections;
}
```

We then make sure the view controller knows how many sections and rows in each section there are, along with the titles of each section (the indexed letters/numbers):

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self.collation sectionTitles] objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.collation sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.collation sectionTitles] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.sectionedArtistsArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
}
```

**3. Displaying the artists**

We then display the artists as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    //We grab the MPMediaItem at the nth indexPath.row corresponding to the current section (or letter/number)
    MPMediaItem *temp = [[self.sectionedArtistsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //Title the current cell with the Album artist
    cell.textLabel.text = [temp valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist];

    return cell;
}
```

You should be good to go. The only issue I have with this is that it fails to escape punctuation (apostrophes etc.) and 'The' prefix of artists. Other than that it works just fine.

Comment: how to play the song on selecting the cell?any help?

Comment: It doesn't look like you use artistArray outside of viewDidLoad; you could probably get rid of that property.

Comment: How are you indexing into the songs? If you were to select a song in the tableview the indexpath for the collation would return only one song. The complete artists array is out of the question because it has no value to indexpath.section.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [iPod Library Access Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). You'll need to make a request and fill your table view with the result. Depending on what you want you could use the [MPMediaPickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingtheMediaItemPicker/UsingtheMediaItemPicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH104-SW1). If you just want the artists you should use an [MPMediaQuery](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

```
MPMediaQuery *artistQuery = [MPMediaQuery artistsQuery];
```

EDIT:

```
NSString *artistKey = [MPMediaItem titlePropertyForGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingArtist];
MPMediaQuery *artistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery artistsQuery];
NSMutableArray *artists = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:artistsQuery.collections.count];

for (MPMediaItemCollection *album in artistsQuery.collections) {
    MPMediaItem *albumItem = [album representativeItem];
    [artists addObject:[albumItem valueForProperty:artistKey]];
}
```

The Documentation for `reprsentativeItem` states:

> The media items in a collection typically share common property
>   values, owing to how the collection was built. For example, if you
>   build a collection based on a predicate that uses the
>   MPMediaItemPropertyArtist property, all items in the collection share
>   the same artist name. You can use the representativeItem property to
>   efficiently obtain values for such common properties—often more
>   efficiently than fetching an item from the items array.

Comment: Yeah, been there, done all that. What is particularly hard to do is to actually index a UITableView with everything the query gives you. When I first tried this 4 weeks ago, I was disappointed when I learned the query doesn't place the objects alphabetically in it's own array.

Comment: "I want to fetch and index all the iPod Library artists in my app", it is useful to say what you have already done in your question and define your problem more clearly.

Comment: - I have mostly tried playing with collections and collectionSections, but there were no ways to fetch the artists alphabetically using them. - I have tried making an NSArray of NSArrays: Each subarray would contain all the artists that start with a given letter. Problem with this method is that when trying to fetch the first letter of each artist, artists that begin with "the", "a", and others would kill the whole indexing.

Comment: Alright this works to do the actual fetching. Still having problems with the actual indexing though, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to look at UILocalizedIndexedCollation

```
- (NSArray *)partitionObjects:(NSArray *)array collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector
{
UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
NSInteger sectionCount = [[collation sectionTitles] count];
NSMutableArray *unsortedSections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];
for(int i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++)
{
    [unsortedSections addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
}
for (id object in array)
{
    NSInteger index = [collation sectionForObject:object collationStringSelector:selector];
    [[unsortedSections objectAtIndex:index] addObject:object];
}
NSMutableArray *sections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];
for (NSMutableArray *section in unsortedSections)
{
    [sections addObject:[collation sortedArrayFromArray:section collationStringSelector:selector]];
}
return sections;
}
```

Place that up top, and use it like so:

```
self.sectionedArray = [self partitionObjects:ArrayOfItemsFromQuery collationStringSelector:@selector(title)];
```

sectionedArray being an NSArray declared in .h.

I think this only works for a list of songs though.

Comment: This solution does work just like Sooper's solution above. You asked for how to Index the library, I told you how. Don't downvote a solution just because you want to have your hand-held the whole way through.

The docs are there for a reason.

Comment: Heya, my deepest apologies for this and for being too late. To be honest, I have no idea of why I downvoted your answer. I was never expecting to get the whole code in a silver plate or anything and any pointer was helpful at that time. - I'm sorry again, I sincerely don't remember why I downvoted this, and I can't "fix" this unless you edit your answer. I'm sorry again.